# How to find out all columns that have 0 non-null values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where I need to find all the columns that have no non-null values.

```
 #   Column                              Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------                              --------------   -----         
 0   LLPIN                               109650 non-null  object        
 1   LLP Name                            45801 non-null   object        
 2   Founded                             25074 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 3   Month                               93439 non-null   object        
 4   State                               62094 non-null   object        
 5   RoC                                 25074 non-null   object        
 6   Class                               2778 non-null    float64       
 7   Status                              27852 non-null   object        
 8   Type                                0 non-null       float64       
 9   Category                            0 non-null       float64       
 10  Obligation of Contribution(Rs.)     45801 non-null   float64       
 11  Paid up capital                     0 non-null       float64       
 12  Industrial Activity                 41819 non-null   object        
 13  Description                         25074 non-null   object        
 14  Address                             46318 non-null   object
```

In the above case, I would like to remove `Type, Category, Paid up capital`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is DataFrame then `df[col].isnull().any()` can judge whether it has null or not.

Get the column name and then drop them.

```py
missing_columns = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].isnull().any()]
reduced_df = df.drop(axis=1, columns=missing_columns)
```

If you want to drop columns without null values, just adding `not` after `if`.

Comment: Hi @JackSong, your solution works after I change the `.any()` with `all()` because I want to remove columns with all `NaN`

Comment: If you want to drop columns that are all NA, you coulduse dropna, like this: `df.DataFrame.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`

Answer (score 0):

Below given code will output all column's names with 0 non-null values:

```
df.columns[df.notna().all()]
```

While to get all non-null column along with their values (dataframe), refer to below code:

```
df.loc[:,df.notna().all()]
```